# Cannot save template constants in typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I updated the constants of my template in the web editor of typo3. Each time I click on Save or Close+Save I get a pop-up from my browser to download a file. The content is like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
</body></html>
```

The minimal example to get this is:

```
page.theme {
  socialmedia.channels {
    facebook.url = https://www.facebook.com/typo3/
  }
}
```

It seams that Typo3 has a problem with the dots in the url. If I remove all of them or escape with a backslash "\" everything works. (But the backslash remains in the url and therefore produce invalid urls)

Some months before everything works fine. Some other templates in the same installation have also urls in their configuration and they are working (the page is rendered normaly). If I try to save them noe without any changes I get the same error.

That is the system I use:

```
Typo3-Version: 9.5.20
Webserver: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix)
PHP-Version: 7.3.21
Database: MySQL 5.6.42
Applicationcontext: Production
OS: SunOS SunOS localhost 5.10 Generic_150401-49 i86pc
Bootstrap Package: 11.0.2
```

Comment: I have experimented a bit. Saving fails every time a valid http/https/mailto URI is present in the script (including in the comments).

Comment: just a strange idea coming to mind: do you have a virus scanner installed or link checker on your system? something that tries to follow URLs and is restricted by firewall or similar?

Comment: As Bernd also suggested, this looks to me like an over-eager intrusion detection system or application firewall. Maybe you have mod_security enabled in Apache? Although 503 usually points to a reverse proxy problem (webserver temporarily not reachable), some security systems are configured to output 503 instead of access denied for "obscurity".